# Удаления значения из словаря при распаковке

Tags: python

В Пайтоне есть возможность, к примеру, скопировать словарь, параллельно добавляя в него новое значение прямо при распаковке:

```
>>> date_info = {'year': '2020', 'month': '01', 'day': '7'}
>>> event_info = {**date_info, 'group': "Python Meetup"}
>>> event_info
{'year': '2020', 'month': '01', 'day': '7', 'group': 'Python Meetup'}
```

Можно отредактировать уже имеющиеся значения аналогичным образом:

```
>>> event_info = {'year': '2020', 'month': '01', 'day': '7', 'group': 'Python Meetup'}
>>> new_info = {**event_info, 'day': "14"}
>>> new_info
{'year': '2020', 'month': '01', 'day': '14', 'group': 'Python Meetup'}
```

Вопрос в следующем: можно ли исключить одну пару значений из словаря при его распаковке. Например, распаковывая `event_info` в `new_info`, как в примере выше, получить на выходе значения `event_info` за исключением `'group': 'Python Meetup'`. Нужен сходный про краткости и удобности способ.

Comment: нельзя, только через генерацию нового или pop

Comment: странное желание. вы понимаете, что не распаковываете один словарь в другой? вы распаковываете один словарь в генератор словаря (dict comprehension). потом вам ничто не помешает воспользоваться del или pop. либо генерируйте новый словарь канонически, с проверкой ключей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [dict compehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

```
>>> {k: v for k, v in event_info.iteritems() if k != 'group'}
{'year': '2020', 'day': '7', 'month': '01'}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Только вот синтаксис `event_info.iteritems()` вроде как устарел (по крайней мере по отношении к версии 3.8), но если вместо этого использовать`iter(event_info.items())`, то работает